# Div container - How to fill it completely?

Tags: html, css

Hi I provided picture of my div container and im trying to say fill the container completely as you can see but i having problem even though my div is in a table and equals other div containers. it just wont fill exactly.

[image]
Thanks you.

what it should look like with borders etc.
[what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDqSr.jpg)

```
<div class="cit">
    <div class="column">
        <h3>Register</h3>
        <img class="cit2" src="images/cit2.jpg">
        <h2 class="divfooter">Step 1 </h2>
    </div>
</div>

html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.cit {
  display: table;
  width: 90%;
}

.column {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 30px;
  overflow: none;
}

h3{
    background: red;
    height: 90%;
}

.cit2{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%
}

.divfooter{
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to fill?  The background? Or change the height to match the outside container?  You haven't properly given a description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: show what you want to with picture.

Comment: You'd also want to include your CSS.

Comment: i had the width and height determined to be 100% at the start. but will show css. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not taking up the entire height is because the parent objects are most likely not 100% as you would like. Place the following code before the container style:

```
html,body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: this code is not useful. `body {margin:0;padding:0}` better than.